# I wasn't expecting this to be how I'd hear of Hulk after ages

Tags: grammar, grammaticality

> **I wasn't expecting this to be how I would hear of you after ages.**

***i would hear*** is future-in-past in this sentence?

Comment: Does this answer your question? ["Would be" usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/233145/would-be-usage)

Comment: I'd say *your* example could be called "future-in-past" (the "current" interaction lay somewhere in the future, back when the speaker was maybe expecting to next hear from the addressee in some *other* way). Which is different to, say, *He is the man who would be king*, where it means this man ***intends, wants to*** become king (whereas *He **was** the man who would be king* is ambiguous, and could carry either of those senses).